# How do I fix a repository with one broken revision?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

My home server had a hard drive failure.

Once I realized the disk was going, I logged in and did a straight copy of my repository, which contains multiple projects.

However, since the disk was failing, one of the revisions is broken:

```
$ svnadmin verify master/
[...]
* Verified revision 820.
* Verified revision 821.
* Verified revision 822.
svnadmin: No such revision 823
```

The `master/db/revs/` and `master/db/revprops/` directories do, indeed, not contain any files called `823`, so this revision is missing (broken). There are subsequent revisions (that I really want to keep!) in the `master/` repository going up to revision #947.

Today I fetched my most recent off-site backup (!), which happily includes this revision. I would like to "heal" the broken repository in `master/` by fixing the missing revision, since it is more recent than the backup.

I made sure to load the dump file into a newly created repository with the same version as the copied one in `master/`, so it's all the old "linear" format 3.

I tried the obvious, to just copy the file `823` from the backup's `db/revs/` and `db/revprops/` directories:

```
$ cp repos/db/revs/0/823 master/db/revs/
$ cp repos/db/revprops/0/823 master/db/revprops/
```

The directory `repos/` contains a repository that has been loaded from the backup dump. Now I get:

```
$ svnadmin verify master/
[...]
* Verified revision 821.
* Verified revision 822.
svnadmin: /build/buildd/subversion-1.6.12dfsg/subversion/libsvn_delta/compose_delta.c:165: search_offset_index: Assertion `offset < ndx->offs[ndx->length]' failed.
Aborted
```

Which is not very encouraging. I've tried various other `svnadmin` commands, but none have made the verifier happy.

My next idea was to back out the copying and start with a "fresh" copy of the broken repository, then dump out the revisions *after* 823, and merge with the backup. But that doesn't seem possible, I can't dump revisions after the missing one:

```
$ svnadmin dump -r 824 master/ >r824.dmp
svnadmin: No such revision 823
```

Note that it doesn't help to make the dump "incremental", in the hopes that it should pretend the world started with revision 824 and just go from there:

```
$ svnadmin dump --incremental -r 824:947 master/ > dump.txt
svnadmin: No such revision 823
```

This does write output to `dump.txt`, but I'm not sure if it can be relied upon. Note that it doesn't log that it successfully dumped *any* revision.

**Update**: I had another idea: to copy the newer revision files from the crashing-disk-copy in `master/` into the backup, to provide the "missing tail":

```
$ for a in $(seq 910 947) ; do cp  master/db/revs/$a repos/db/revs ; cp master/db/revprops/$a repos/db/revprops/ ; echo $a ; done
```

However, this seems to do nothing but corrupt the target repository:

```
$ svnadmin verify repos/
[...]
* Verified revision 907.
* Verified revision 908.
* Verified revision 909.
svnadmin: Corrupt representation '907 21815 45 30922 158d3e72732f45bf6f02919b22fc899a'
svnadmin: Malformed representation header
```

Now, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Starting to think that maybe this had been better served at one of the other StackExchange sites, but there seemed to be many similar questions here.

Comment: It's ok, questions about version control tools are fair game here. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers", and version control is rarely used in other fields (at least by non-programmers).

Comment: About recovery of corrupted repositories, I just found this very interesting article : 
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/06/svn-corruption-recovery/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I solved it.

The solution was (of course) obvious, once I realized it.

I had this:

- `master/`: A copy of a broken repository, featuring revision 0..947, with revision 823's files physically missing.
- `repos/`: A repository loaded from a backup (dump file), covering revision 0..910.

The solution was simply to dump from `master/`, from revision 911 and onwards. This was possible without any errors, which I take it means that none of the revisions in the range 911..947 directly depended on the state in revision 823, or something:

```
$ svnadmin dump --incremental -r 911:947 master/ > tail.txt
* Dumped revision 911.
* Dumped revision 912.
* Dumped revision 913.
[...]
* Dumped revision 947.
```

Anyway, then just apply the dump to the repository coming from the backup:

```
$ cat tail.txt | svnadmin load repos/
[lots of commits]
```

And now I have the full history restored, no problems:

```
$ svnadmin verify repos/
* Verified revision 0.
* Verified revision 1.
* Verified revision 2.
[...]
* Verified revision 945.
* Verified revision 946.
* Verified revision 947.
```

Yay!